# Incosistent results on Firefox and Chrome while assigning base64 image data as src to image

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I am trying to draw checkbox image on canvas by assigning base64 image data as src to image object.It works fine on IE but give inconsistent results on Firefox and Chrome
Here is my code

```
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDgAPAPcAAAAAAIAAAACAAICAAAAAgIAAgACAgMDAwMDcwKbK8BxRgCGhIeLi3ePj3+Xl4efn4+rq5uzs6e/v7PHx7/Pz8fX18/f39vn5+Pr6+fz8+/39/f7+/v///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/78KCgpICAgP8AAAD/AP//AAAA//8A/wD//////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAOAA8AhwAAAIAAAACAAICAAAAAgIAAgACAgMDAwMDcwKbK8BxRgCGhIeLi3ePj3+Xl4efn4+rq5uzs6e/v7PHx7/Pz8fX18/f39vn5+Pr6+fz8+/39/f7+/v///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/78KCgpICAgP8AAAD/AP//AAAA//8A/wD//////whzADkIHEiQoIKDCBMi5KCAgcMGDh5AiCBhAgUFDB9GnFiRQgWMDSFKpDhhQQULIEVyLLnAwgWQEReQXEDzAgaQEmmyXGAzA8iJNIP21AByZk0MGTRsANmxAk+kShkytHhy6AaBID26hHoVK0OFYDEWHDswIAA7';
    ctx.drawImage(
        img,
        sx, 
        sy, 
        sw, 
        sh, 
        dx, 
        dy, 
        dw, 
        dh      
        );
```

If i put an alert after assigning src to image then it works with FF and chrome even.I guess its all because of javascript asynchronous behaviour, before complete src is assigned to image the drawing process takes place hence not getting complete image.
Could any one tell me how to handle this problem .

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting for the image onLoad event before drawing the image. And be sure to add the handler before assigning the src attribute.

```
 img = document.createElement('img');
 img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
 };
 img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGO...OFYDEWHDswIAA7';
```

Also try this (in most browsers it should result in the exact same thing, but some older browsers do have issues with one or the other method):

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function() { 
    ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
 }
 img.src = "data:img/gifx;base64....";
```

If this still doesn't work consistently on Firefox and Chrome you might try adding the image to the DOM to see if that makes any difference:

```
 img = document.createElement('img');
 document.body.appendChild(img);
 img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
 };
 img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGO...OFYDEWHDswIAA7';
```

Comment: I am still struggling with this issue, your suggestion solved one of my problem where i was facing same issue with canvas.todataURL().I have tried all three options suggested above but still not able to make it draw on canvas,if i put alert after assigning src the same code works.

Comment: Try using setTimeout with a timeout of 0. This will wait until the current code execution is finished

setTimeout(function() {
  // Set img.src
}, 0);